# Would 401 Error be a good choice?

Tags: seo, http-headers

On one of my sites have a lot of restricted pages which is only available to logged-in users, and for everyone else it outputs a default "you have to be logged in ... " view.

The problem is; a lot of these pages are listed on Google with the not-logged-in-view, and it looks pretty bad when 80% of the pages in the list have the same title and description/preview.

Would it be a good choice to, along with my default not-logged-in-view, send a 401 unauthorized header? And would this stop Google (and other engines) to index these pages?

Thanks!

(and if you have another (better?) solution I would love to hear about it!)

Comment: I don't know much about SEO but you could try using a sitemap to tell search engines which pages to crawl / their importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the status codes googlebot understands and recommends.
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40132
in your case an HTTP 403 would be the right one.

Answer (score 4):

Use a robots.txt to tell search engines not to index the not logged in pages.

http://www.robotstxt.org/

Ex.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /error/notloggedin.html
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently working in. I just wanted to get some feedback on this method since it would make things less "painful" because you wouldn't have to add every page to Disallow.

Comment: `User-agent` is just an suggestion for search engines. It could happen, if anybody links to your pages, that they still will be added to the search index.

Comment: @Jan: No, not for any of the search engines; they all obey robots.txt. No matter where the link comes from, they won't index the page if it's blocked by robots.txt.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, I think you are right. Actually, robots.txt is not an official standard and a colleague told me that he had trouble with robots.txt on a private family blog. To validate this, I have set up two pages on different (sub-)domains. One with a robots.txt that allows crawling, one that does not allow it. If both show up in a search index list, my colleague is right, if not, he made a mistake and robots.txt seems to be safe. I have to link both domains here to let search engine's crawler find them: http://robots-allow.smilinginthesun.de/ http://robots-disallow.smilinginthesun.de/

Comment: @Jan, links from SO use nofollow so they won't be crawled. You'll have to link them from somewhere else. Also in my previous comment I meant to type "all *major* search engines". There are likely bots out there calling themselves search engines and ignoring robots.txt.

Comment: Hi @DisgruntledGoat, thanks for that 'nofollow' hint. It was the google bot my colleague talked about. Please do not understand me wrong. This is more of a test that my colleague made a mistake, than to check all the crawler out there, or your answer resp. Maybe, this is not the place to test this, but I was so interested that I could not help but try it.

Answer (score 3):

`401 Unauthorized` is the response code for requests that requires user authentication. So this is exactly the response code you want and have to send. [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

EDIT: Your previous suggestion, response code `403`, is for requests, where authentication makes no difference, eg. disabled directory browsing.

Comment: Oh, forgot about 401. Edited my question.